# How to automatically update one google sheet based on the data available in other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have two different google sheets; one with the leads data and the other with unsubscribe data. Is there a way to automatically update the lead's data whenever a new unsubscribe email is added to the unsubscribe sheet? If the leads data has any email which is in the unsubscribe list, the data related to that email should be automatically removed.

Here is the sheet with sample data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zhPRjQnrsD7B51ig7M5G8LnYte_3h07jx6pRNXnCSM4/edit#gid=2100307022

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168554/edit) your question and insert two [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that show a sample of leads data and unsubscribe data, together with a third table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` and `match()`, like this:

```
=filter( A4:C8, isna(match(A4:A8, A11:A15, 0)) )
```